# Why is JSON-lib 4x slower with Java 8 than Java 6

Tags: java, json

I find [JSON-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/faq.html) parsing for large json files 4x slower on Java 8 than Java 6.

I tested on a Linux 64 bit machine.

You can download the ready to run code with required jar files from [here](http://aredis.sourceforge.net/jsonLibTest.zip).

Below is the source code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;


public class JsonLib {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        String sampleJsonPath = "sample.json";
        byte [] b = new byte[2048];
        int totalRuns = 50;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            totalRuns = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        int len;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bop = new ByteArrayOutputStream(8192);
        InputStream ip = new FileInputStream(sampleJsonPath);
        while ((len = ip.read(b)) > 0) {
            bop.write(b, 0, len);
        }
        ip.close();
        String countryJson = new String(bop.toByteArray());
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long runStart = start;
        long runEnd;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalRuns;) {
            JSONObject.fromObject(countryJson);
            i++;
            if (i % 10 == 0) {
                runEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("PARSE TIME for run " + (i-10) + '-' + i + " = " + (runEnd - runStart));
                runStart = runEnd;
            }
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total time = " + (end -start));
    }
}
```

The code parses a large json file 50 times printing the time for every 10 runs.

Java 6 takes around 1.5 seconds whereas Java 8 takes 7 seconds.

In my company we have worked around this issue by moving to jackson parser.

But still it would be great if someone can shed more light on the reason for the slowness of Java 8 in this particular case.

Comment: Run a profiler (NetBeans, VisualVM, ...) on this and it should show you where the time is lost

Comment: It *might* be caused by the change to the implementation of `String`, where `substring` now copies the backing `char[]`. Since you are stringifying the byte array, you're giving `JSONObject` a very large string. In Java 6, substrings off that string would share the `char[]`. In Java 8, substrings copy the relevant section. If you instead created the `JSONObject` using a `JSONTokener`, performance might be similar.

Comment: @Andreas http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue230.html ?

Comment: @Marged Thanks. I've never seen an article on the topic, I just noticed the change in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Change in implementation of String.substring seems to be the root cause because I see a similar slowness in Java 7 also.